# Logstash Date filter not working properly

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I was trying to filer message to get timestamp and use date filter to convert the string to date but the converted date different as of original.

Filter code:

```
filter {
   grok {
      match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \| %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} \| %{NOTSPACE:taskid} \| %{NOTSPACE:logger} \| %{WORD:label}( \| %{INT:duration:int})?" ]
   }
  
   date {
      match => ["timestamp", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
      target => "timestamp"
   }
}
```

input

```
2021-04-19 12:06:39,586 | INFO | 12345 | TASK_START | start
```

output

```
 "timestamp" => 2021-01-19T06:36:39.586Z,
```

the hour and minute have changed

Comment: Instead of using grok in that case, you could use the dissect filter, which should be more performant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logstash and elasticsearch store dates as UTC, and kibana will map that to the browser's timezone. By default a date filter will use the local timezone. So if you are in the Asia/Kolkata timezone, which is +05:30 compared to UTC, this is working exactly as expected. If the timestamp field is in a different timezone then use the timezone option of the date filter to tell it which one.

Answer (score 2):

If timestamps in your logs are not UTC you can provide timezone information.
For example:

```
date {
    match => ["timestamp", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    timezone => "Asia/Kolkata"
    target => "@timestamp" // <--- this is optional, @timestamp is default
}
```